# draw points using x and y coordinates from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html5-canvas

I'm reading x and y coordinates from my database, counting how many rows are there to coincide the number of points that will be drawn on my canvas:

```
        <?php
                          $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
                          // Check connection
                          if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                          }

                          $sql = "SELECT id FROM sample";

                          if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
                          // Return the number of rows in result set
                          $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                          // Free result set
                          mysqli_free_result($result);
                          }

                          mysqli_close($conn);
                        ?>
                        var val = '<?php echo $rowcount; 
          ?>';
```

I want to plot the points using the given x and y positions from the database. **I'm trying to use a loop to draw all the points from the database using a multidimensional array and this is where my problem comes in.** I am having a difficulty on how to solve it

```
    for(var i = 0; i < val; i++)
    {
        <?php
                          $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
       // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                          }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM sample";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
        $points= array( array("x" => $row['x']),
        array("y" => $row['y'])); 

        //x, y coordinates 
        $x_pos = $points['x'];
        $y_pos = $points['y'];
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
        var x = '<?php echo $x_pos; ?>';
        var y = '<?php echo $y_pos; ?>';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x , y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
     }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  What is actually happening?

Comment: i get no display after i added the drawing of points using the x and y from the database. but when i tried assigning random x and y, it showed drawn points based on the number of rows on my database

Comment: Open the page and do "view source" to see what is being rendered.  That's what we need to see, unless the PHP is not working correctly.

Comment: i get no error but my canvas has been hidden after i placed my xy query and array

Comment: You have nested PHP code inside javascript code. However these run at different times. PHP code runs (once) on the server while your page is being generated and renders what will be inside the javascript code. Then the javascript code runs on the browser iterating over the same x/y values.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis what should i do to iterate different values? i'm new to javascript and i don't quite understand how array works in js

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment you are nesting PHP code inside a loop in javascript assuming PHP code will run for every iteration of the loop. However that is not true. PHP code runs on the server and renders the inside of the loop once. Then the loop runs on the browser iterating over the same values.

Here what I think you wanted to write:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM sample";

    echo 'var points=[';
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
        foreach( $result as $row ) {
            echo "{x:${row['x']}, y:${row['y']}},";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    echo "];\n";
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>


for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var p = points[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x , p.y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
 }
```

Here's an explanation of the code above:

PHP code runs on server, queries the database and echoes the data points as a javascript variable declaration/initialization. The echoed variable declaration along with the following javascript code is sent to the browser and runs there. The javascript code iterates over the array variable and creates the paths.

Comment: thanks for the help but does that mean that i won't be using the counting of rows which i have done above before i place the x and y values in an array?

Comment: Counting of rows is not necessary unless you need it for something else on the server (client will get the row count anyway in the form of the literal array). Even then, you don't need a separate query as you will need to get all the rows anyway. Then you can get the count from the `$result` array.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i tried following your code but i only get a blank canvas as an output

Comment: I haven't tried the code so there I might have missed something. You should check the source in your browser. Does the `var points = [....];` declaration look correct?

Comment: Javascript `for (... in ...)` should not be used to iterate arrays. I have updated the code accordingly